# Django admin, how select several fields and edit at once

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-actions

Good time. How to do following in Django admin:

1. For example, I have model called Events. I have some events created. I have fields like event name, .... and also field "planning Date"
2. I need set the same date in "planning Date" field for 5 events.
3. I am selecting 5 events in checkbox and need in one action do it.

I mean something like  delete action for selected objects.

Answer (score -1):

If your field is a boolean or an action without a user value, you can use admin action:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions

If you need a user value inside, read this : https://www.willandskill.se/en/custom-django-admin-actions-with-an-intermediate-page/

Comment: Thanks,  but it is not really what I need.

Comment: Wow, what i missed? i was pretty sure my answer was relevant